# Python Program to Display News Headlines?

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a program that displays the current news headlines. I tried the python module newspaper, but had issues with the instillation. Does anyone know another way to go about this task? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [feedparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) module to fetch RSS info from your preferred newspapper.

**RSS Source Examples:**

- https://www.ft.com/news-feed
- http://www.reuters.com/tools/rss
- http://www.economist.com/rss
- https://www.rsssearchhub.com/feeds/

**Code example:**

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://www.reddit.com/r/python/.rss')
print d['feed']['title']
print d['feed']['link']
print d.feed.subtitle
```

**Output:**

```
>>> Python
>>> http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/
>>> news about the dynamic, interpreted, interactive, object-oriented, extensible programming language Python
```

If you have any doubt, you can take a deep look at the [PythonForBeginners Feedparser Tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/feedparser/using-feedparser-in-python).

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps!